# YUI3 events not working in Firefox or Opera, works fine in Chrome though

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom-events, yui

I have a very simple YUI3 script which changes background of a web page. Here is the source:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>YUI 3 events do not work!</title>
</head>
<body id="doc-body">
<div id="rgbvalues"> </div>
<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/yui/yui-min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//use node and event modules
YUI().use("node", "event", function(Y){
    var handleClick = function(e) {
        var docBody = Y.one("#doc-body"); //equivalent to $(element) in prototype and jQuery(element)
        var winHeight = docBody.get('winHeight');//get "viewport" height
        var winWidth = docBody.get('winWidth');//get "viewport" width
        var red = parseInt (e.pageX * (255/winWidth));
        var green = parseInt(e.pageY * (255/winHeight));
        var blue = parseInt (red*green*0.004);
        var bgstyle = "rgb("+red+","+green+"," +blue+")";
        console.log("setting background-color:"+bgstyle+" for #doc-body");
        docBody.setStyle("background-color", bgstyle);//same as $(element).setStyle() from prototype and jQuery(element).css()
        Y.one("#rgbvalues").set("innerHTML", bgstyle);//set innerHTML
    };
    Y.on("mousemove", handleClick, "#doc-body");
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script doesn't work in Firefox 5 or Opera but works well in Chrome. There is no error on Firebug console either. Even if I change the event from `mousemove` to `click` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your problem, add this CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}
```

The `html` and `body` elements do not take up 100% height by default.

The reason for the inconsistent behaviour between browsers is probably to do with the fact that your page is using [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), because you don't have a doctype. Add this as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: That's the reason why FF and Opera wont register the mousemove event but chrome would somehow do.

Answer (score 1):

It appears it's not an event related issue but rather in the way the CSS rule is handled.

Try add the `stylesheet` module:

```
YUI().use("node", "event", "stylesheet", function(Y) {
```

and apply the rule not using `setStyle` but:

```
Y.StyleSheet().set('#doc-body', {
    backgroundColor: bgstyle
});
```

Tested with FF5/Win and Explorer 8 and it works, unfortunately I can't try using Chrome. There is a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/JDxkD/) for demo purposes; if you'd also like to read some docs please consider [YUI 3: StyleSheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/stylesheet).

**Disclaimer:** I'm not a YUI3 expert so there could be better ways to solve the issue.

Comment: As far as I understand its related to event, notice that `console.log("setting background-color:"+bgstyle+" for #doc-body");` isn't fired at all, in chrome, the console is flooded with log but nothing in FF or Opera, got some one to test it on IE and it works on IE

Comment: @Kumar If you want to see the events in console remove the comment sign from the line containing the console statement.

Comment: you wont believe what corrected the problem, I just changed `docBody.setStyle("background-color", bgstyle);` to `docBody.setStyle("background", bgstyle);` but still in chrome, the values in `rgbvalues` div update instantly, it doesn't work same in FF, background color changes that too abruptly

Comment: @Kumar excerpt from the page I linked: "In essence, it looks very much like natural CSS syntax, except style properties must be in JavaScript's camelCase.". For this reason backgroundColor (or simply background) works and background-color doesn't.

Comment: Right, but that still doesn't explain why the values in `rgbvalues` div change so smoothly in Chrome and not so smoothly in FF