# background or background-color? Which one is safe to use?

Tags: html, css, yui

I just now found that when I try to change `background-color` using YUI for a body it doesn't work in FF5 and Opera but works in IE and Chrome. However, if I set color values for `background` it works in FF as well as Opera. I thought that `background-color` was just some sort of specialisation for `background`. Which one can be used safely across all browsers? Code in question can be seen here, [background or background-color? Which one is safe to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930302/background-or-background-color-which-one-is-safe-to-use), I still have problem understanding how YUI handles events. I have also hosted the page with modified code here http://www.kumarchetan.com/yui-module.html, try accessing this page using IE, Chrome, FF and Opera and notice how smoothly the values change in different browsers.

Comment: Can you show some code please. background-color works fine for me in FF5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem, add this CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}
```

The `html` and `body` do not take up 100% height, which is what you need to handle `mousemove` events. The `background` for the root element [is handled specially](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-background/#special-backgrounds), but that's not the same as having 100% height.

The reason for the inconsistent behaviour between browsers is possibly to do with @BoltClock's edit, and also probably to do with the fact that your page is using [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), because you don't have a doctype. Add this as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: thanks a ton! I will treat myself with a drink and you are welcome as well :) but another question why would Chrome behave differently...

Comment: Can you cross-post the solution to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922672/yui3-events-not-working-in-firefox-or-opera-works-fine-in-chrome-though? I will close that question as well

Answer (score 3):

This is because the [YUI CSS reset](http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/cssreset/reset.css) sets the `background` property on the `html` element rather than `body`, so if you want to specify a different page background color, do it for `html`. It isn't related to any compatibility issues between `background-color` and the shorthand `background` whatsoever, as both properties are fully supported (the CSS1 version, anyway) in all browsers.

**EDIT:** oh you mean you were using YUI's JavaScript APIs... in that case, it's a discrepancy with the DOM style properties. Indeed, you have to use camelCase notation for cross-browser compatibility (this doesn't just apply to YUI, but the DOM in general). IE and Chrome just happen to support hyphenated property names too.

Comment: @thirtydot: Sorry for stealing your limelight ;)

Comment: @BoltClock, man I aint using no css. Its plain old vanilla HTML page with YUI. Have a look at the source and you will understand.

Comment: @Kumar... so what are you talking about in your question if not CSS?

Comment: argh!!! you had me here, what I meant was I am not using Y! reset.css, its plain html with little CSS, it turns out that YUI doesn't recognise `background-color` in fact it recognises `backgroundColor`. I faced same issue with `z-index`, YUI wants it to be `zIndex`, stupid or what I dont know. Now the issue still remains why the original code with `background-color` worked in Chrome but not in FF/Opera.

Comment: @boltclock, sorry, thirtydot got the credit :P come over for a drink ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There's no real difference between the two unless you're setting an image and a colour. If you're only setting one thing then you might as well just use `background`.

Answer (score 0):

They both can be used safely across all browsers.

`background` can set all it's sub-attributes, such as `background-color, background-image, background-position` etc.

So instead of setting

```
background-color: #fff; /* white */
background-image: url(path/to/image.png);
background-repeat: repeat; /* or repeat-x, repeat-y, none */
background-position: top center; /* other options include bottom, right, left, along with pixel values and percentages*/
background-attachment: scroll; /* or fixed */
```

you can write
`background: #fff url(path/to/image.png) top center fixed;`

Answer (score 0):

*+1 to BoltClock's answer, since that's probably the right one in this case, however I have actually had a similar situation with a different solution recently, so I thought I'd share.*

In my case, the element in question had a gradient background:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #c2c2c2, #ffffff);
```

Setting the `background-color` had no effect on this element, since the gradient took precedence over the color. I had to use `background` to override it.